# Dynamic graph in C++11 with shortest path algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, design-patterns, graph

I've been designing a dynamic graph to improve my understanding of C++11. The dynamic aspect means that it could represent the hyperlink structure of a chunk of the internet, with node deletion corresponding to removing dead links. I'd be grateful for a review of coding style/design patterns/optimization.

The main conceptual changes from my [previous attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115864/object-oriented-approach-to-dijkstras-algorithm) is that I have abstracted away the shortest paths algorithm using the *Strategy* pattern. In the main function I give two concrete examples using the Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford algorithm.

I have also implemented the Observer-Observable pattern with the `Node`s playing the role of observables. The motivation for using the observer pattern was to decouple the `Node` class from the mutable `Heap` class which is used in the Dijkstra algorithm.

**Headers**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <list>
```

**Observer**

```
class Observable;

class Observer {
public:
    virtual ~Observer() {}
    virtual void update(Observable* = nullptr)=0;
    void registerWith(Observable* observable);
};

class Observable {
public:
    Observable() : observer_(nullptr) {}
    void notifyObserver();
    void registerObserver(Observer* observer);
private:
    Observer* observer_;
};

inline void Observer::registerWith(Observable* observable)
{
    if (observable) observable->registerObserver(this);
}

inline void Observable::notifyObserver()
{
    if(observer_) observer_->update(this);
}

inline void Observable::registerObserver(Observer* observer)
{
    observer_=observer;
}
```

**Heap**

```
template<class Compare>
class Heap : Observer {
public:
    // implements priority queue data ADT
    void insert(Observable* val);
    Observable* extract_min();
    void build_min_heap() { for (int i = arr_.size()/2 ; i >= 0 ; --i) min_heapify(i); }
    int heapSize() const { return arr_.size(); }
    void print() const;
    void update(Observable* p);
private:
    void indexSwap(Observable* a, Observable* b);
    void min_heapify(int i);
    int parent(int i) { return i/2; }
    int left(int i) { return 2*i; }
    int right(int i) { return 2*i+1; }
    // underlying array
    std::vector<Observable*> arr_;
    // keeps track of locations in array
    std::unordered_map<Observable*,unsigned int> lookup_;
};

template<class Compare>
void Heap<Compare>::insert(Observable* val)
{
    unsigned int n  = arr_.size();
    lookup_[val] = n;
    arr_.push_back(val);
    update(val);
    registerWith(val);
}

template<class Compare>
void Heap<Compare>::indexSwap(Observable* a, Observable* b)
{
    unsigned int temp = lookup_[a];
    lookup_[a] = lookup_[b];
    lookup_[b] = temp;
}

template<class Compare>
void Heap<Compare>::update(Observable* p)
{
    int i = lookup_[p];
    while ( i > 0 && !Compare()(arr_[parent(i)],arr_[i]) )
    {
        indexSwap( arr_[i], arr_[parent(i)] );
        std::iter_swap( arr_.begin()+i, arr_.begin()+parent(i) );
        i = parent(i);
    }
}

template<class Compare>
void Heap<Compare>::min_heapify(int i)
{
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    int smallest;
    if ( l < arr_.size() && Compare()(arr_[l],arr_[i]) ) { smallest = l; }
    else { smallest = i; }
    if ( r < arr_.size() && Compare()(arr_[r],arr_[smallest]) ) smallest = r;
    if ( smallest!=i )
    {
        // swap position i with smallest
        indexSwap( arr_[i], arr_[smallest] );
        std::iter_swap( arr_.begin()+i, arr_.begin()+smallest );
        min_heapify(smallest);
    }
}

template<class Compare>
Observable* Heap<Compare>::extract_min()
{
    Observable* min = arr_[0];
    indexSwap( arr_[0], arr_[arr_.size()-1] );
    std::iter_swap(arr_.begin(),arr_.begin() + arr_.size()-1);
    // run min_heapify on the decremented heap
    arr_.pop_back();
    min_heapify(0);
    return min;
}
```

**Graph**

```
template<class Label, class Edge>
class Graph {
public:
    class SPEngine;
    Graph(const std::shared_ptr<SPEngine>& engine = std::shared_ptr<SPEngine>()) : engine_(engine) {}
    void setSPEngine(const std::shared_ptr<SPEngine>& engine) { engine_ = engine; }
    void addNode(const Label& name);
    void deleteNode(const Label& name);
    // adds a directed edge pointing from name1 to name2
    void addEdge(const Label& name1, const Label& name2, Edge w = 1);
    void printNeighbors(const Label& name);
    void shortestPaths(const Label& start);
    struct CompareNode;
    struct Node;
    void relax(Node* u, Node* v);
    // returns a pointer to a node given its label
    Node* pointerOf(const Label& name);
    std::unordered_map<Label,std::unique_ptr<Node>> lookup_;
private:
    struct isSame;
    std::shared_ptr<SPEngine> engine_;
};

template<class Label, class Edge> class
Graph<Label,Edge>::SPEngine {
public:
    virtual ~SPEngine() {}
    virtual void apply(Graph<Label,Edge>& g, const Label& start) = 0;
};

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Graph<Label,Edge>::shortestPaths(const Label& start) {
    engine_->apply(*this,start);
    // print out the shortest path weights
    for (auto it = lookup_.begin(); it != lookup_.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << "(" << it->second->label_ << "," << it->second->d_ << ")" << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template<class Label, class Edge> struct
Graph<Label,Edge>::Node : public Observable {
    Node(const Label& name) : label_(name), Pi_(nullptr), d_(0) {}
    ~Node();

    // node identifier
    Label label_;

    // incoming and outgoing nodes
    std::list< std::pair<Node*, Edge> > outgoing_;
    std::list<Node*> incoming_; // to handle node deletions
    void addOutgoing(Node* p, Edge w) { outgoing_.push_back( {p,w} ); }
    void addIncoming(Node* p) { incoming_.push_back(p); }
    void removeOutgoing(Node* p);
    void removeIncoming(Node* p);

    // predecessor/distance data structure for shortest paths method
    Node* Pi_;
    Edge d_;
};

template<class Label, class Edge>
struct Graph<Label,Edge>::isSame {
    isSame(Node* n) : n_(n) {}
    bool operator()(const std::pair<Node*,Edge>& elem) const { return n_ == elem.first; }
private:
    Node* n_;
};

template<class Label, class Edge>
struct Graph<Label,Edge>::CompareNode {
    bool operator()(Observable* u, Observable* v) const {
        return ((Node*)u)->d_ < ((Node*)v)->d_;
    }
};

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Graph<Label,Edge>::relax(Node* u, Node* v)
{
    // find the weight of the edge pointing from u to v
    typename std::list< std::pair<Node*, Edge> >::iterator it
    = std::find_if( u->outgoing_.begin(),u->outgoing_.end(),isSame(v) );
    if ( it != u->outgoing_.end() ) // if there is an edge pointing from u to v
    {
        Edge w = it->second;
        // check relaxation condition
        if (u->d_ == std::numeric_limits<Edge>::max() && w > 0) return; // corrects mathematical bug
        if (v->d_ > u->d_ + w)
        {
            v->d_ = u->d_ + w;
            v->Pi_ = u;
            v->notifyObserver(); // v was modified
            return; // (u,v) was relaxed
        }
        return; // (u,v) was not relaxed
    }
    return; // (u,v) does not exist
}

template<class Label, class Edge>
Graph<Label,Edge>::Node::~Node()
{
    // for each incoming node n, remove 'this' pointer from n's list of outgoing
    for (auto it : incoming_) {
        it->removeOutgoing(this);
    }
    for (auto it : outgoing_) {
        it.first->removeIncoming(this);
    }
    std::cout << "Node " << this->label_ << " destroyed.\n";
}

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Graph<Label,Edge>::addNode(const Label& name)
{
    try {
        if (pointerOf(name)) throw 0;
        lookup_.emplace(name,std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(name)));
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION: Graph already contains node with same label.\n";
    }
}

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Graph<Label,Edge>::deleteNode(const Label& name)
{
    try {
        Node* p = pointerOf(name);
        if (!p) throw 0; // throw if it's not there
        lookup_.erase(name);
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION: Graph does not contain node with that label.\n";
    }
}

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Graph<Label,Edge>::addEdge(const Label& name1,const Label& name2, Edge w)
{
    Node* n1 = pointerOf(name1);
    Node* n2 = pointerOf(name2);
    if (n1 && n2) { // if both name1 and name2 exist
        n1->addOutgoing(n2,w);
        n2->addIncoming(n1);
    }
}

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Graph<Label,Edge>::printNeighbors(const Label& name)
{
    try {
        Node* n = pointerOf(name);
        if (!n) throw 0;
        for (auto it : n->outgoing_) std::cout << "(" << it.first->label_ << "," << it.second << ")" << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "EXCEPTION: Graph does not contain node with that label.\n";
    }
}

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Graph<Label,Edge>::Node::removeOutgoing(Node* n)
{
    typename std::list< std::pair<Node*, Edge> >::iterator it
    = std::find_if(outgoing_.begin(),outgoing_.end(),isSame(n));

    try {
        if ( it == outgoing_.end() ) throw 0;
        outgoing_.erase(it);
        std::cout << "Removed " << it->first->label_ << " from " << this->label_ << "'s" << " outgoing list.\n";
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Failed to remove " << n->label_ << " from " << this->label_ << "'s" << " outgoing list.\n";
    }
}

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Graph<Label,Edge>::Node::removeIncoming(Node* n)
{
    typename std::list<Node*>::iterator it
    = std::find(incoming_.begin(),incoming_.end(),n);

    try {
        if ( it == incoming_.end() ) throw 0;
        incoming_.erase(it);
        std::cout << "Removed " << (*it)->label_ << " from " << this->label_ << "'s" << " incoming list.\n";
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Failed to remove " << n->label_ << " from " << this->label_ << "'s" << " incoming list.\n";
    }
}

template<class Label, class Edge>
typename Graph<Label,Edge>::Node* Graph<Label,Edge>::pointerOf(const Label& name)
{
    typename std::unordered_map<Label,std::unique_ptr<Node>>::iterator it = lookup_.find(name);
    if ( it != lookup_.end() ) {
        return it->second.get();
    }
    else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

**Dijkstra**

```
template<class Label, class Edge>
class Dijkstra : public Graph<Label,Edge>::SPEngine {

private:
    // priority queue for Dijkstra
    Heap<typename Graph<Label,Edge>::CompareNode> Q;
public:
    void apply(Graph<Label,Edge>& g, const Label& start);
};

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Dijkstra<Label,Edge>::apply(Graph<Label,Edge>& g, const Label& start)
{
    // initialize distance estimates
    for (auto it = g.lookup_.begin(); it != g.lookup_.end(); ++it) it->second->d_ = std::numeric_limits<Edge>::max();
    typename Graph<Label,Edge>::Node* pstart = g.pointerOf(start); // maintain pointer for future use
    pstart->d_ = 0;
    // create a set to store processed nodes
    std::unordered_set<typename Graph<Label,Edge>::Node*> S;
    // insert initialized nodes into priority queue in correct order
    Q.insert(pstart);
    for (auto it = g.lookup_.begin(); it != g.lookup_.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->second.get() != pstart) Q.insert(it->second.get());
    }

    while (Q.heapSize()!=0)
    {
        typename Graph<Label,Edge>::Node* u = static_cast<typename Graph<Label,Edge>::Node*>(Q.extract_min());
        S.insert(u);
        // for each neighbor v of u, perform relax(u,v)
        for (auto it : u->outgoing_)
        {
            g.relax(u,it.first);
        }
    }
}
```

**Bellman_Ford**

```
template<class Label, class Edge>
class Bellman_Ford : public Graph<Label,Edge>::SPEngine {

public:
    void apply(Graph<Label,Edge>& g, const Label& start);
};

template<class Label, class Edge>
void Bellman_Ford<Label,Edge>::apply(Graph<Label,Edge>& g, const Label& start)
{
    // initialize distance estimates
    for (auto it = g.lookup_.begin(); it != g.lookup_.end(); ++it) it->second->d_ = std::numeric_limits<Edge>::max();
    typename Graph<Label,Edge>::Node* pstart = g.pointerOf(start);
    pstart->d_ = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= g.lookup_.size()-1; ++i) {
        for (auto it1 = g.lookup_.begin(); it1 != g.lookup_.end(); ++it1) {
            typename Graph<Label,Edge>::Node* u = it1->second.get();
            for (auto it : u->outgoing_) {
                g.relax(u,it.first);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> nodes = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"};
    std::string v = nodes.front();
    std::vector< std::pair<std::string,std::string> > edges =
    {
        {"a","b"},{"b","c"},{"c","d"},
        {"c","e"},{"e","f"},{"b","f"},
        {"f","g"},{"g","a"},
        {"h","i"},{"i","j"},{"j","d"},
        {"f","h"},{"j","f"},{"f","d"}
    };

    Graph<std::string,int> myGraph;

    for (auto it : nodes) myGraph.addNode(it);
    for (auto it : edges) myGraph.addEdge(it.first,it.second);

    std::shared_ptr<Dijkstra<std::string,int>> dijkstra(new Dijkstra<std::string,int>);
    std::shared_ptr<Bellman_Ford<std::string,int>> BF(new Bellman_Ford<std::string,int>);

    myGraph.setSPEngine(dijkstra);
    std::cout << "Performing Dijkstra starting at vertex " << v << ":\n";
    myGraph.shortestPaths(v);
    myGraph.setSPEngine(BF);
    std::cout << "Performing Bellman_Ford starting at vertex " << v << ":\n";
    myGraph.shortestPaths(v);
}
```

## Output

> ```
> Performing Dijkstra starting at vertex a:
> (h,3) (g,3) (f,2) (c,2) (e,3) (j,5) (d,3) (b,1) (i,4) (a,0) 
> Performing Bellman_Ford starting at vertex a:
> (h,3) (g,3) (f,2) (c,2) (e,3) (j,5) (d,3) (b,1) (i,4) (a,0) 
> Removed h from f's outgoing list.
> Removed h from i's incoming list.
> Node h destroyed.
> Removed g from f's outgoing list.
> Removed g from a's incoming list.
> Node g destroyed.
> Removed f from e's outgoing list.
> Removed f from b's outgoing list.
> Removed f from j's outgoing list.
> Removed f from d's incoming list.
> Node f destroyed.
> Removed c from b's outgoing list.
> Removed c from d's incoming list.
> Removed c from e's incoming list.
> Node c destroyed.
> Node e destroyed.
> Removed j from i's outgoing list.
> Removed j from d's incoming list.
> Node j destroyed.
> Node d destroyed.
> Removed b from a's outgoing list.
> Node b destroyed.
> Node i destroyed.
> Node a destroyed.
> ```